# Extruder driver not working

Tags: motor, extruder-driver

I have a [geeetech g2s pro](https://www.geeetech.com/wiki/index.php/Geeetech_G2_%26_G2s_pro) and when I request to print something, the extruder motor doesn't move (it is connected on the board), therefore, the printer prints some kind of imaginary object. I cannot ask Repetir host to extrude it as prevents moving when the extruder is cold, and when it is hot all the repetier host does is moving the header up. Is there a way a could test these motors without needing a hot extruder?

Here you have a picture of it, maybe it is upside down.[image: motor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I had to swap the cables on the board, now they are working.